# How do I get the value of an object by key in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, object, associative-array

I'm getting data using 
var result = $.getJSON.

When I console.log(result); I get this object:

```
Object
    abort: function (a){a=a||"abort",p&&p.abort(a),w(0,a);return this}
    always: function (){i.done.apply(i,arguments).fail.apply(i,arguments);return this}
    complete: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
    done: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
    error: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
    fail: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
    getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return s===2?n:null}
    getResponseHeader: function (a){var c;if(s===2){if(!o){o={};while(c=bH.exec(n))o[c[1].toLowerCase()]=c[2]}c=o[a.toLowerCase()]}return c===b?null:c}
    isRejected: function (){return!!e}
    isResolved: function (){return!!e}
    overrideMimeType: function (a){s||(d.mimeType=a);return this}
    pipe: function (a,b,c){return f.Deferred(function(d){f.each({done:[a,"resolve"],fail:[b,"reject"],progress:[c,"notify"]},function(a,b){var c=b[0],e=b[1],g;f.isFunction(c)?i[a](function(){g=c.apply(this,arguments),g&&f.isFunction(g.promise)?g.promise().then(d.resolve,d.reject,d.notify):d[e+"With"](this===i?d:this,[g])}):i[a](d[e])})}).promise()}
    progress: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
    promise: function (a){if(a==null)a=h;else for(var b in h)a[b]=h[b];return a}
    readyState: 4
    responseText: "{'result':'success'}"
    setRequestHeader: function (a,b){if(!s){var c=a.toLowerCase();a=m[c]=m[c]||a,l[a]=b}return this}
    state: function (){return e}
    status: 200
    statusCode: function (a){if(a){var b;if(s<2)for(b in a)j[b]=[j[b],a[b]];else b=a[v.status],v.then(b,b)}return this}
    statusText: "OK"
    success: function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
    then: function (a,b,c){i.done(a).fail(b).progress(c);return this}
__proto__: Object
```

How do I get the value for the statusText key? (which in this case is "ok");

I've tried console.log(result.statusText) and console.log(result['statusText'] but both return as undefined. What gives?

EDIT: Here's the actual code I'm using.

```
 $j(".buyNowButton").click(function(){
      var qty = $j(this).attr('qty');
      var product_id = $j(this).attr("product_id");

      var params = "product_id=" + product_id + "&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;qty=" + qty;        

      var result = $j.getJSON("/acumen/scripts/addToCart.php", params, function(data, textStatus){
            console.log(textStatus);
           if (textStatus == "error"){
                alert("There was an error adding this item to your cart.  Please call customer service for assistance.", "Error");
                return;
           };
           if (data.result == "error"){
                alert("Sorry, an error occurred while adding the item to your cart.  The error was: '" + data.message + "'");
                return;
           };
      }); 
      console.log(result);
 });
```

Comment: It is in fact `result.statusText`. You'll have to post the code you're using for anybody to help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not using the object correctly. When you use `console.log(result)`, the only reason you're seeing the result text is because the Firebug console updates the reference values. If you tried to access `result.statusText` in code at that same line, you'd not get your result because the request likely hasn't actually finished yet.

This line:

```
var result = $.getJSON
```

Is giving you the request object itself. If you want to deal with the response, you do so in a callback function:

```
$.getJSON('request/url/goes/here', request_data, function(result) {
    // this is where you do something with your json data
});
```

... understanding that `getJson` is a "quick alias" for doing this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'request/url/goes/here',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: request_data,
  success: function (result) {
      // this is where you do something with your json data
  }
});
```

You say that the response is the text "ok"; I would suggest then that you not use `getJson`, as that expects the response to be json data. Instead:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'request/url/goes/here',
  data: request_data,
  success: function (result) {
      // this is where you do something with your response string "ok"
  }
});
```

.. note that I am not specifying the data type of the callback as json. jQuery will auto-detect it.

**Documentation**

- `jQuery.getJSON` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
- `jQuery.ajax` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

It's simply:

```
result.statusText
```

Answer (score 0):

your `result` variable is a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) that `$.getJSON()` returns, not your JSON data. You need to use a success callback.

Here is a simple example of how to use getJSON:

http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/